# Slick Slider, maintain changing slides on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have this code for my slick slide, which (on hover over next arrow) it will change slides to the next slide.

The problem I am having is that when the user is hovered over the next arrow I want the slides to continuously go to the next slide as long as that hover is maintained. Right now on hover it just goes to the next slide then stops and I have to re mouseover to get the next slide to come in.

Any suggestions on how I can make it continuesly change slides as long as the hover stays, and when it leaves no longer change the slide.

Thank You!

JavaScript

```
var $showcaseSlider = $(".showcase-slider").slick({
infinite: true,
slidesToShow: 6,
slidesToScroll: 1,
cssEase: 'linear',
arrows: true,
dots: false,
pauseOnHover: true,
pauseOnFocus: true,
centerMode: true,
responsive: [
 {
   breakpoint: 992,
   settings: {
     slidesToShow: 3,
     slidesToScroll: 1
   }
 },
 {
   breakpoint: 480,
   settings: {
     slidesToShow: 2,
     slidesToScroll: 1
   }
 }
]
});

$(".showcase-slider .slick-next").on('mouseover', function(){
    $showcaseSlider.slick('slickNext');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Ended up figuring this out. At first I thought about using a interval, but decided to go with recursive timeout for cleaner code.

```
var sliderTimeout;

function changeSlideNext(){
  $showcaseSlider.slick('slickNext');
}
function recursiveSlideChangeNext(){
  changeSlideNext();
  sliderTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
   recursiveSlideChangeNext();
  },1000);
}
function killSlideChange(timer){
 window.clearTimeout(timer);
}

$(".showcase-slider .slick-next").on('mouseover', function(){
   recursiveSlideChangeNext();
 });

$(".showcase-slider .slick-next").on('mouseout', function(){
   killSlideChange(sliderTimeout);
});
```